# Filter Logic Help Please

Tags: filters

[image]When I run my report with the below filter logic, it will only return 1 AND 2, but not 3,4,5.  I am sure it has to do with my parenthesis, any thoughts?  I would like to be able to return either 1 and 2 or 3 and 4 and 5.  Thank you.

Comment: Your times may be the issue. There isn't a time in the day that's _before_ 8 AM (less than) and _after_ 7 PM (greater than). Build your criteria out one step at a time (`(1 AND 2) OR (1 AND 3)`, verify that you get back every day of the week, then tweak from there: `(1 AND 2) OR (1 AND 3 AND 4)` etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try step by step first.  Is there a better way to do a time range that you are aware of?

Comment: Thank you, I was able to create based on step by step approach.  How can I mark as best answer?  (1 AND 2) OR (1 AND 3 AND 4)

Comment: I just left that as a comment and not as an actual answer so you can't mark it as the best answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

As @nbrown mentioned, your times are the issue because you can't ever be both *before* 8:00AM AND *after* 7:00PM.

I suspect you're trying to pull in records that were created outside of normal business hours, meaning on the weekend or early/late in the day during the week. If that is the case, you probably want:

```
1 AND (2 OR (3 AND (4 OR 5)))
```